# How to sort the map basis on the value

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to store the bundle name and its latest version in the Map.

Below is my `newDirs` which is an `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>()` from which I am supposed to get the Bundle name and its latest version-

```
[{objectName=/storage/Model/Framework/1.0.0/, objectId=4fa042a5a56c861104fa05c246cf850522a2354ca223, objectType=DIRECTORY}, 
{objectName=/storage/Model/Framework/1.0.1/, objectId=4fa042a5a66c860d04fa056bbe1cf50522a14094ca3f, objectType=DIRECTORY}]
```

Now from that above List, I am supposed to extract the latest version of `Framework bundle` . So in the above case, it is `1.0.1 version` and the bundle name is `Framework`. So my map will store `Framework` as the Key and `1.0.1` as the version of the bundle in the above case.

Below is my code-

```
final List<Map<String, String>> newDirs = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

for(String ss : list) {

    //some code here for newDirs

    Map<String, String> map = storageDirectorySort(newDirs);
    System.out.println(map);
}

/**
 * Sort the list and then return the map as the Bundle Name and its Latest version
 *
 */
private static Map<String, String> storageDirectorySort(List<Map<String, String>> newDirs) {

    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    // do the sorting here and always give back the latest version of the bundle and its name

    return map;
}
```

Can anybody help me with this. I am not sure what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You want another helper method** to help parse the version number. Then call it in your storageDirectorySort method:

```
    private static int getVersion(Map<String, String> dir) {
        String objectName = dir.get("objectName");
    // Get the various parts of the name
        String[] nameParts = objectName.split("/");
    // Get the version from the nameParts
        String[] versionString = nameParts[nameParts.length - 1].split("\\.");
        // Parse version String into an int
        return (Integer.valueOf(versionString[0]) * 1000000)
                + (Integer.valueOf(versionString[1]) * 10000)
                + (Integer.valueOf(versionString[2]) * 100);
    }

    private static Map<String, String> storageDirectorySort(
            List<Map<String, String>> newDirs) {

        Map<String, String> latestVersion = null;
        for (Map<String, String> bundle : newDirs) {
            int version = getVersion(bundle);
            if (latestVersion == null || version > getVersion(latestVersion)) {
                latestVersion = bundle;
            }
        }

        return latestVersion;
    }
```

Note: There is no exception handling in this code, I would recommend adding some.  Other than that, I have tested it to verify that it works.